Getting SQL UPDATE to work the same as SQL DELETE wrt Cascading Ref in PostgreSQL
I've constructed a table in Postgres (v14.4) like this:
CREATE TABLE public.comments 
(
    comment_id uuid NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    media_id uuid NOT NULL,
    user_id uuid NOT NULL,
    parent_id uuid NULL,
    comment text NOT NULL,
    date_created timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    date_updated timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    date_deleted timestamptz,

    CONSTRAINT fk_comments_parent
        FOREIGN KEY(parent_id)
            REFERENCES comments(comment_id) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

I added some sample data to the table:

I then ran this SQL command:
DELETE FROM comments 
WHERE comment_id = '198332bc-ee11-421b-b33f-3a711a94c0b0'

As expected, this deleted the last record shown in the screenshot and the 2nd record shown, which is connected via the parent_id.  Great.
I restored all of the data and then tried this
UPDATE comments 
SET date_deleted = '2024-09-08 10:30:00.000 -0400' 
WHERE comment_id = '198332bc-ee11-421b-b33f-3a711a94c0b0'

I was expecting date_deleted to be thusly set in both records (parent and child) but it was only set in the parent record.
Simply put, how come the UPDATE CASCADE didn't update date_deleted for the 2nd record shown in the screenshot?
Am I doing something wrong or is what I'm asking Postgres to do currently impossible?

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Doing something wrong. From the docs CREATE TABLE: CASCADE Delete any rows referencing the deleted row, or update the values of the referencing column(s) to the new values of the referenced columns, respectively.

You are misunderstanding what ON UPDATE CASCADE does. What is does is the following: if you update comment_id in a row in comments to a new value X, the column parent_id in all rows that reference that row is also updated to X.  In short, the referencing rows are automatically updated so that they still reference the modified row.
The foreign key does not establish a reference between any other columns in the affected rows, so such columns are not updated.
What you want can best be achieved with a row-level trigger.

A dbfiddle, which shows this: https://dbfiddle.uk/yG9KmISt

Interesting.  Thank you.   Indeed yes, I thought that ON UPDATE CASCADE was essentially the UPDATE equivalent of ON DELETE CASCADE.

It is the closest equivalent, I'd say. I guess your confusion is because you have a foreign key from a table to itself, so the referenced row happens to have the same columns. In general, the only columns that the two tables have in common are the key columns. They are the only ones that have a relationship with each other. But even in your example, it is not automatically clear that the date_deleted columns ought to be related.
